# Two way files synchronization using WinSCP

Tags: sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Is it possible to perform a 2 way files synchronization using WinSCP, so that any files deleted on the source sftp folder would be deleted on the local folder and vice versa?
And any files added to either would sync?

Comment: Thanks Martin, this worked wonders, it deletes and updates both ways based on the latest changes, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.